# Get model object in category

Tags: python, django

In my current models. I have 2 models. I have a category and boards model

```
class Categories(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Board(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categories, related_name='topics', on_delete=False)
```

I have a for loop displaying all the categories, and I plan to write one to display the boards that belong in that category.But my for loop just displays EVERY board in EVERY category. Where I need the boards where category equals test to display in the category test
But Im using

```
boards = Board.objects.all()
```

How would I make it so I only get my for loop would display the board in the correct category?

Comment: `my_category.board_set.all()`.

Comment: How would I use this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
category = Category.objects.get(name='somename')
boards = Board.objects.filter(category=category)
```

Since you've defined a `related_name`, you could also just do this:

```
boards = category.topics.all()
```

Comment: Can you explain this I bit more? I'tried the first one but I seems I have  create another one of those each time I add a new category?